# Gitlab runner failed to connect to docker deamon

Tags: docker, windows-server, gitlab-runner

Im on Windows Server 2019, Docker EE 20.10.7, running gitlabrunner 14.7.0 and im getting

```
Preparing the "docker-windows" executor
00:09
ERROR: Failed to remove network for build
ERROR: Preparation failed: error during connect: This error may indicate that the docker daemon 
is not running.: Get "http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.25/info": open 
//./pipe/docker_engine: Zugriff verweigert (docker.go:853:0s)
```

After restarting the docker deamon and running one docker command from command line, the builds are running fine, until a few days later, the problem starts again and i need to restart the docke deamon and fire one "docker ps" for example. Than it works again a few days. My user is in the docker group
deamon.config:

```
{
"group" : "docker"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved, had multiple instances of gitlab-runner.exe running on the same config, wich causes trouble.